# Is it possible and safe to switch between the motors when required?

Tags: stepper-motor, switching, stepper-driver, brushed-dc-motor

I want to control a two phased stepper motor in an application, so I chose [this driver](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/256/tmc5130_datasheet_ecf0a-2498292.pdf). There is also a requirement for a brushed DC motor in the application. I want to save space eliminating an extra dedicated driver for DC motor and microcontroller IOs (takes up to 5 GPIOs for the DC motor driver.)

I am planning to connect it as shown in the below figure to one of the pairs of the driver output. On page 102 of the datasheet, it says a DC motor can be controlled with some config change. Both the motors never run at the same time in the application but one at a time. Is it possible to do so? Is it safe? What is the best way to do so?

[image]

The stepper motor needs 24V and 0.94A . The DC motor needs 5V and 1.3A for controlling at peak.

I am aware that it is also required to switch between 24V and 5V as the motor voltage supply (+VM) when switching between the motors when possible. Please shed some light.

Comment: How would you prevent current from flowing through the DC motor when the stepper is working? In any case you could use a relay or, more elegantly, a MOSFET to open/close one of the lines to the DC motor. If your main problem is _wasting_ more pins from your MCU, why not considering a port expander instead?

Comment: @DanielMelendrez, yes, with the help of mosfets or an IC that would help current not flowing into the DC motor. Getting an extra driver and passive elements for the driver eats up space on PCB, is also one of the problems I wanted to avoid. Getting a port expander is a good suggestion. Thanks. But from the technical POV, i am just curious to know if this option is a good or a bad design or is it even possible/ sensible for such an application.

Comment: The problem I see here is that if you do not properly isolate the two motors from the driver's shared port, the effective load will be small and thus you are at risk of damaging it (Bridge B in your picture). I personally would NOT consider this a good design. Saving space in this type of application can be counter-productive. Additionally, your PCB layout _MUST_be carefully thought out. Consider adding proper ground planes, and separate analog and digital grounds (with proper coupling). When doing so, you will notice that saving space should be your last concern when laying out motor drivers.

Comment: @DanielMelendrez Agreed. Thanks a lot for the inputs

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Firstly I appreciate your effort. But I dont know where you found the data you just mentioned. The driver is capable of driving a stepper motor upto 46V and 2.5 Amps peak, which is stated in the first page:- Features and Benefits. And in the page 102, section 23: _ "The TMC5130A can drive one or two DC motors using one coil output per DC motor. Either a torque limited operation, or a voltage based velocity control with optional torque limit is possible" _. An overlook? Thanks.

Comment: @CoppersCopernicus Please don't post duplicate questions

Comment: @VoltageSpike Pardon. I forgot to close the previous question. The question despite directing towards the same obejective regards to a completely different driver chip in this question. Anyhow thanks for highlighting

Comment: I can delete it if you'd like

Comment: @VoltageSpike Yes please. Thanks

Comment: ROFL  Nevermind.  I must of read the data sheet wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that following proper PCB layout practices for your motor driver is the best approach for your case.

Please study carefully [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva959b/slva959b.pdf?ts=1664371587488&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) document which will give you valuable guidelines for proper grounding, shielding, current and thermal considerations, etc.

As @StainlessSteelRat commented, your original idea isn't viable.

Comment: Useful. But what @StainlessSteelRat mentioned with the numbers is still incomprehensible and contradictory to what I read on the datasheet